# Save dialogue hangs in XE2

Tags: delphi, runtime, themes, delphi-xe2, tsavedialog

I use Delphi XE2 on Windows 8. I have ported an D2009 application to XE2 and suddenly the save dialog (TSaveDialog) is very slow.

When Project/Options/Application/Runtime Themes is set to Enable Runtime Themes:

=>

When I open the save dialog the window freezes for about a minute (sometimes I can close the window but have to wait about a minute until I can open the dialog again (or another TOpenDialog). The new Vista style save dialog is shown.

If I try to run this exe on a PC with Windows 7, the app hangs upon start (I did also try with XP compatibility mode without success).

When Project/Options/Application/Runtime Themes set to none:

=>

Save dialog works well (fast) but the old style dialog is shown, se example below:

[image: Example old style dialog]

This exe works well on a PC with Windows 7 (though with the old style dialog).

Ps. My old exe-file compiled with D2009 on a Win 7 PC works however well on both the Win 7 and 8 PC:s, and shows the dialogs correctly using the new Vista dialog style.

Could it be some permission rights in Win 8/7 causing this? I use IDE FIX PACK 5.4,

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: is your windows fresh or anything is installed ? for example TeamViewer had interference with XE2 dialogs ( but it caused them lagging for few second on closing, not opening ) Perhaps even some videodrivers having features about managing layouts of windows like AMD HydraVision may potentially interfere

Comment: Does this happen in Release mode or Debug mode only?

Comment: Does behaviour change if you run without IDE?

Comment: Does it behave the same with a brand new project?

Comment: @Arioch 'The: The PC is about 1 year old and many things are installed but not the ones you mention.

Comment: @RawN: It has the same behaviour.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It is same within the IDE, or standalone execution.

Comment: This must be environmental.

Comment: I know it's a very old version, but don't you have TortoiseSVN 1.6.14 or below installed ?

Comment: In debug mode (with option Enable Runtime Themes):

1. I open the savedialog
2. I give file name and press the save button => nothing happens. 
3. I need to press the save button for at least one more time after 30-60 seconds in order for the compiler to continue to row
>   if SaveDialog1.Execute then

(It works also if I open the save dialogue and wait about 1 minute before I press the save button.)

After this it will continue normally. If I try to save again, I have the above problem.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: It works fine with a brand new project in all cases (debug/release, IDE/standalone, Enable Runtime Theme on/off), and the new Vista style dialogue is always shown...!

Comment: @Thomas - You've most possibly seen the related question on the right which suggests COM initialization as culprit. I also recall problems related with "image file execution options" registry key, initial directory/file name being wrong. Probably not with the exact symptoms you describe though..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: 
I am not sure how to check any COM faulty initialization.

There are no key entrance for my app in "image file execution options".

Changing the initial directory/file names did not help. 

When ”runtime themes” is enabled, the open and save dialogues are very slow (I have a fast I7 PC with SSD-disk). The folder ”my documents” also shows to be empty in the dialog even though there are folders and files in it. When ”runtime themes” is disabled, I have no problem viewing the folders (but with the old style file dialogues). Could it have something to do with e.g. VirtualStore/UAC?

Comment: @Thomas - I'd be inclined to think no, but I don't really know. Maybe you can disable functionality in your app part by part until the dialog gets going, to figure out what may be causing this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem is. I use {$MAXSTACKSIZE $4000000} and this causes the save dialogue to freeze for about a minute.
The reason for this hefty stack size is that I use a recursive algorithm (that I now probably need to remake).

Reproduce as follows (XE2):

1. Create a new VCL forms application
2. Place a TSaveDialog1 on the form
3. Place a Tbutton with OnClick event

`

```
Begin
   if SaveDialog1.Execute then    
     MessageDlg('ok', mtInformation,[mbOk], 0);
end;
```

`

4: Open the project source file and put the following rows:

//{$MAXSTACKSIZE $3500000} //this is a decimal value of 5 5574 528  OK!

{$MAXSTACKSIZE $4000000}   //this is a decimal value of 6 7108 864  Not OK!

Run and click the button. Give a dummy file name and press save. Nothing happens. Keep on clicking the button for 60 seconds. The dialogue will finally close.

Change to the smaller stack size $3500000. Now the program works well. Thanks for all tips.